# How can i get the access.log from the openshift platform

Tags: php, apache, openshift, paas

I built a app ,and i choose the php language.I see that **openshift** platform use the Apache Server.

**now i want to check the access.log? how can i find it?**

thx!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would just be to just run `rhc tail YOUR_APP_NAME` from the command line tools.

To view the logs on the remote server:

```
rhc ssh YOUR_APP_NAME # ssh into your app
cd $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR # change to the log directory
tail -f php.log
```